# Default value to another bean property when Source is null MapStruct

Tags: java, mapstruct

Well, I have the following Mapper in MapStruct:

```
 @Mapping(source = "payload.after", target = "payload")
 TargetEntity toTarget(SourceEntity source);
```

Sometimes `payload.after` is null and I need to fill with another property, called `payload.before`. Something like this:

```
 @Mapping(source = "payload.after", target = "payload")
   //OR, if payload.after is null
 @Mapping(source = "payload.before", target = "payload")
 TargetEntity toTarget(SourceEntity source);
```

I tried used in this way but didn't work:

```
 @Mapping(source = "payload.after", target = "payload", defaultValue = "payload.before")
 TargetEntity toTarget(SourceEntity source);
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From MapStruct docs I see that only you can use predefined values: https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#default-values-and-constants

But you can easily do it by using annotations like `@AfterMapping` or `@BeforeMapping` check in MapStruct docs examples :)

EDIT:

```
@Mapping(target = "otherTargetField", source = "otherSrcField")
TargetEntity toTarget(SourceEntity source);

@AfterMapping
void toTargetAfterMapping(@MappingTarget TargetEntity, SourceEntity source) {
   // Your after mapping logic with payload.before and payload.after
}
```

MapStruct auto-resolves that this method is called at the end of the mapping method before the last return statement. If you want to know more see [MapStruct docs - customising mappings with before and after](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#customizing-mappings-with-before-and-after).

Another approach which you can use is a [defaultExpression](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#default-expressions)

```
@Mapping(target = "payload", source = "payload.after", defaultExpression = "java(source.getPayload().getBefore())")
TargetEntity toTarget(SourceEntity source);
```